# assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to compare floating-point numbers in a matrix

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a program to find the min and max in from a given matrix with 5 elements. But now I want to find the min and max in a matrix  with *floating-point numbers*. Supposedly using assertEquals that would be possible but I don't truly get it how to use it.
I got a hint like this: **assertEquals**(expected, actual, delta)
But I do not go far from that, I don't understand how could I use it. If you could help me I very much appreciate it

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement to use assertEquals?

Comment: Yes originally I thought of doing it in a different way but I have to use assertEquals for a school project

Comment: If you used `assertEquals(1.0., 1.0)` it will return true, but if the actual is the result of a computation, it may not be _exactly_ equal, just _approximately_ equal. Set a float to 0.1f  and add it together 10 times. The result is 1.0? No, because it's binary math, it's actually 1.0000001. The delta is how close the values need to be to 'equal'. What its actually does is `Math.abs(expected - actual) < delta`. Recommended reading for floating point: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

Last argument is delta. You can pass expected & actual values in the first two arguments.

True:

```
Assert.assertEquals(0.0010f, 0.0013f, 0.0003f);
```

Above is true because 0.0003 <= (0.0013 - 0.0010 = 0.0003)

False:

```
Assert.assertEquals(0.0010f, 0.0013f, 0.0004f);
```

Aboove one is false because 0.0004 > (0.0013 - 0.0010 = 0.0003)

Comment: Okay, I see how it works here. But for example, let's say I have matrix like : {1.24444,0.004,5.56,9.335,2,65} that are being saved in a variable **private double[] values**  how could I compare them to find the highest and minimum value?

Comment: Another thing, when I write _Assert.assertEquals_ the program does not recognize the word **Assert** as reserved word

Comment: You can have two assert statements for two different conditions. The above code is for org.junit.Assert . I hope you are using JUnit Test cases.